# Minimum Number of Distinct Distances

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given that the upper bound on the number of unit distances determined by n points in a real space is $ cn^\frac{4}{3} $

Give a lower bound on the min. number of unique distances.

I am really struggling with this, any thoughts appreciated. Thanks

Attempt 1:

I know that the total distances = $n^2$

Let

$$ T = Total \space Distance = n^2$$
$$ U = Unit \space Distance \le cn^\frac{4}{3} $$
$$ K = Distinct \space Distances $$

So, $\space $ T = U + K

$$ T - K \le cn^\frac{4}{3}$$
$$ n^2 - K \le cn^\frac{4}{3}$$

Therefore

$$ K \ge n^2(1-cn^\frac{2}{3}) $$

Is this correct? The big question is does the equation T = U + K hold?

Comment: No, it does not hold: if there are three unit distances and seven distances of length $2$, then $T = 10$ and $U = 3$, but $K = 2$.

Comment: The idea here is that the unit distance bound also gives you a bound on the number of repeated distances of *any* fixed length (can you see why?).

Comment: Assuming you mean $n^{-2/3}$, your purported lower bound is $\Omega(n^2)$.  Just take $n$ equally spaced points on a line to see why this cannot possibly be a correct lower bound.

Comment: I can see why the equation is wrong, but I dont know how else to approach this.

Comment: My second comment above is already a hint for how to approach this.